# How to Scrape Product Pages using Python grequests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, grequests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import grequests
import pandas as pd
    
# STEP 1: Create List of URLs from main archive page
def get_urls():
    urls = []
    for x in range(1,3):
        urls.append(f'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{x}.html')
        print(f'Getting page url: {x}', urls)
    return urls

# STEP 2: Async Load HTML Content from page range in step 1
def get_data(urls):
    reqs = [grequests.get(link) for link in urls]
    print('AsyncRequest object > reqs:', reqs)
    resp = grequests.map(reqs)
    print('Status Code > resp (info on page):', resp, '\n')
    return resp

# Step 3: Extract title, author, date, url, thumb from asynch variable resp containing html elements of all scraped pages.
def parse(resp):
    productlist = []

    for r in resp:
        #print(r.request.url)
        sp = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        items = sp.find_all('article', {'class': 'product_pod'})
        #print('Items:\n', items)

        for item in items:
            product = {
            'title' : item.find('h3').text.strip(),
            'price': item.find('p', {'class': 'price_color'}).text.strip(),
            'single_url': 'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/' + item.find(('a')).attrs['href'],
            'thumbnail': 'https://books.toscrape.com/' + item.find('img', {'class': 'thumbnail'}).attrs['src'],
            }
            productlist.append(product)
            print('Added: ', product)
            
    return productlist

urls = get_urls() # (Step 1)
resp = get_data(urls) # (Step 2)
df = pd.DataFrame(parse(resp)) # (Step 3)
df.to_csv('books.csv', index=False)
```

The above script works as expected by **asynchronously scraping** the **main archive page** or pages for the website https://books.toscrape.com/ using **grequests** and **BeautifulSoup**.

Within the archive page it extracts the following book information:

- title
- price
- single product url
- thumbnail url

## Issue

I need a way to further **extract information from the single product pages** for information such as UPC and associate the information back to the main array **productlist**.

**Single Product Page Example**: https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The single page information you need `UPC` `Product Type` ,`reviews` etc...
`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}
r = requests.get("https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html?")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
table = soup.find("article", class_="product_page")

header = [th.get_text(strip=True) for th in table.tr.select("th")][1:]
header.insert(0, 'S.No')

all_data = []
for row in table.select("tr:has(td)"):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select("td")]
    all_data.append(tds)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=header)
print(df)

output:
                      S.No
0         a897fe39b1053632
1                    Books
2                   �51.77
3                   �51.77
4                    �0.00
5  In stock (22 available)
6                        0
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. Unfortunately, this does not solve my issue. Your script simply scrapes the archive page (slowly). My script does the same only quicker using asynchronous scraping. My issue is that i do not know how to scrape the single book pages and return those results back to the main array productlist.

Comment: what information yu need for `single book page`

Comment: ok I update the code

Comment: I have `update` the code check it`

Comment: You have simply scraped a static page. I have asked for a solution based on scraping all pages based on urls.append(f'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{x}.html') in Step 1, to be carried out asynchronously Step 2 and lastly appended to the main array productlist Step 3 that stores all the scraped info from the archive page.

Comment: you need the information of all  page ??